# How to add a key/value pair to object in javascript using a function

Tags: javascript

```
var myObject = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
};

function addToMyObject(item) {
    myObject.item;
    console.log(item + " has been added to your object.");
    console.log(myObject);
}

addToMyObject(key3 = "value3");
```

I understand I could convert my object to an array, but could I do this to an object?

Comment: You can either push on an object with a key and value, or you could pass in an array of 2 items `[key, value]`

Comment: @Fallenreaper `push()` doesn't work on objects.

Comment: Sorry, wrong verbage.

Comment: You need to pass two separate arguments, one with the name, the other with the value.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks guys! Sorry if this was a duplicate, when I searched couldn't find anything relating to adding to an object using a function, thanks for the help!!